Why aren't Laravel's flash messages persisting after redirect in Laravel 11, and how can I fix this while still using the redirect()->with() method?
Laravel 11: Can't Get Both Normal Sessions and Flash Messages Working Simultaneously
Problem
I'm experiencing a conflict in Laravel 11 where I can only get either normal sessions OR flash messages to work, but not both:

When middleware is commented out: Flash messages work, but normal sessions don't persist
When middleware is uncommented: Normal sessions work, but flash messages disappear after redirect

Code
Controller:
public function switchLang(Request $request, $locale)
{
    $request->session()->put('locale', $locale); // Normal session
    
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('flash_message', '语言更换成功.') // Flash message
        ->with('flash_type', 'success');
}

View:
{{-- Flash Message --}}
@if(session('flash_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('flash_type', 'info') }}">
        {{ session('flash_message') }}
    </div>
@endif

{{-- Normal Session --}}
{{ session('locale') }}

app.php Configuration that makes flash work but breaks normal sessions:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        // Commenting these out makes flash messages work but breaks normal sessions
        // $middleware->use([
        //     \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        //     \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //     \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        // ]);
    })
    ->create();

app.php Configuration that makes normal sessions work but breaks flash:
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        // Uncommenting these makes normal sessions work but breaks flash messages
        $middleware->use([
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->create();

config/session.php:
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => env('SESSION_ENCRYPT', false),
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),
    'table' => env('SESSION_TABLE', 'sessions'),
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => env('SESSION_PATH', '/'),
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),
    'http_only' => env('SESSION_HTTP_ONLY', true),
    'same_site' => env('SESSION_SAME_SITE', 'lax'),
    'partitioned' => env('SESSION_PARTITIONED_COOKIE', false),
];

Debug Logs
When flash works (but normal sessions don't):
[2024-11-21 02:26:00] First Request:
{
    "_token": "o5IooR4tva9abbacvE14SPzS1EKR7XKj7RKO8UWt",
    "_flash": {"old": ["flash_message", "flash_type"], "new": []},
    "flash_message": "语言更换成功.",
    "flash_type": "success"
}

When normal sessions work (but flash doesn't):
{
    "_token": "o5IooR4tva9abbacvE14SPzS1EKR7XKj7RKO8UWt",
    "_flash": {"old": [], "new": []},
    "locale": "en"
}

Environment

Laravel Version: 11
PHP Version: 8.2
Session Driver: database
Session Configuration: Using database driver

What I've Tried

Using session()->flash()
Using redirect()->with()
Toggling middleware configuration in app.php
Checking middleware order
Verified session table exists and migrations are up to date
Created custom flash implementation (works, but want to use Laravel's built-in functionality)

Tags: laravel, php, sessions, flash-messages, laravel-11

is it not better to use laravels flash function $request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
